# Akka tutorial code does not run

Tags: java, eclipse, akka, noclassdeffounderror

The tutorial code from

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.2/intro/getting-started-first-java.html

Will not run. I have imported the required libraries but get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/typesafe/config/ConfigFactory
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:93)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.create(ActorSystem.scala:56)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem.create(ActorSystem.scala)
    at Pi.calculate(Pi.java:152)
    at Pi.main(Pi.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    ... 5 more
```

Anyone know how to get this working? I'm trying to run it in Eclipse.

Note: I'm running akka 2.1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not actually using Akka 2.0.2: the Config library only became an external dependency in 2.0.3. Since you are getting started with Akka, may I suggest you look at the latest stable version 2.1.2 instead?

Concerning the problem at hand: you will need to add the artifact "com.typesafe"/"config" to your classpath (the exact version depends on which Akka version you are using, I suggest using a dependency management tool like Maven or SBT).

Here's a link to the documentation (including required Scala versions etc) for each major version of Akka: http://akka.io/docs/

Comment: Also, adding the only com.typesafe version I have makes no change to the error.

Comment: It is not about what you have; which dependency management tool do you use? Also, you should apply the version of the docs which matches the version of the software you want to use. Wrt. the Config library you need http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.typesafe%7Cconfig%7C1.0.0%7Cbundle

Comment: I thought I'd be ok just manually adding Jars, but it looks like akka fails unless you use maven or the like. Cheers for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Well, you can use Akka without Maven, you just need to manually do exactly what Maven would have done ;-)

Comment: Alternatively, use SBT. The config files are easier to read than Maven's if you can get past the "%" and "%%" magic (which is actually quite helpful).